# Por que o fetch está retornando uma promise e não os dados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, react, vue.js

Pessoal estou fazendo um fetch para pegar os dados de um JSON, porém a variável está ficando com o valor da promisse e não dos dados retornados.

```
var data = fetch('./data/data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(result => { return result; });

console.log(data);
```

Como eu poderia fazer para retornar os dados e não a promise?

Answer (score 2):

Você está fazendo errado, exemplo de retorno `json`

```
fetch('./data.json')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Work with JSON data here
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
  })
```

ou seja, nesse código tem um método `then` tem um `console.log(data)` e o resultado que esperado, e não é o `data` que realmente é um `promisse`, no seu ***código***:

```
var data = fetch('./data/data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(result => { console.log(result); });
```

a variável `result` é o retorno que precisa que vai trazer os dados do `json`.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Doc. Usando Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)</sup>

Como o usuário quer de resgatar o valor faça um [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Callback_function):

```
function res(data) {
    // utiliza o valor aqui ...
}

var data = fetch('./data/data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(result => { res(result); });
```

ou então [async/await](https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp):

```
var data = await fetch('./data/data.json');
var result = await data.json();
```

se estiver dentro de uma função tem que colocar um `async` para resolver as `promisses` exemplo:

```
async function resultJson(){
    var data = await fetch('./data/data.json');
    return await data.json();
}
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Async And Await to the Rescue](https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp)</sup>

Vale lembrar que tudo isso depende de como está implementando e também verifique a melhor forma de fazer para o seu contexto.

Comment: Virgilio Novic muito obrigado pela atençao, mas como eu jogo os dados para fora do escopo do fetch? A intenção seria que var data estaria em um escopo global.

Comment: respondido @user8811593 ...