# Chave de objeto não é reconhecida após usar fetch

Tags: javascript, api, front-end, promises, fetch

O console indica um errado dizendo Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
sendo que dentro do escopo da função em que acesso a API consigo acessar name e demais chaves.

o código:

```
function swapiGet(params){
    const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/${params}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json =>  json)
    
    
    
}
function preencherAssets(){
   personagens.innerHTML =  swapiGet("people/1/").name;
   console.log('primeiro')

}
preencherAssets();
```

Alguém sabe a razão e como resolver?
Comecei a estudar promises e consumir APIs recentemente.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem dois problemas nas funções que apresentou:

1. Em momento algum você retorna o valor na sua função `swapiGet`;
2. O retorno do `fetch` é uma `Promise`, portanto você deve aguardá-lo antes de utilizar.

```js
const swapiGet = (params) => {
  const url = `https://swapi.dev/api/${params}`;

  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json());
};

const preencherAssets = ({
  name,
}) => {
  personagens.innerHTML = name;
  console.log('primeiro');
};

swapiGet('people/1/').then(preencherAssets);
```

```html
<span id="personagens"></span>
```

---

Saiba mais sobre `Promises` nas respostas das seguintes perguntas:

- [**Por que o fetch está retornando uma promise e não os dados?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438739/por-que-o-fetch-est%C3%A1-retornando-uma-promise-e-n%C3%A3o-os-dados)
- [**Como realmente aprender a usar promessas em JavaScript?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16921/como-realmente-aprender-a-usar-promessas-em-javascript)
- [**O que é callback?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback)
- [**Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript)
- [**Como eu posso utilizar o async/await do javascript?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211505/como-eu-posso-utilizar-o-async-await-do-javascript)